# Extracting Beam Member Forces from STAAD using VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem on creating a macro for a certain situation.
I have a STAAD model which has 8 beams and 10 load cases.
I wanted to get the beam end forces for all the beams but only
load cases 1 and 2.

Here's the code

```
Sub ExtractLC_Click()

Sheets("COPING BEAM").Range("A:I").ClearContents

'Variable Declaration

Dim lMemberNo As Long
Dim lEnd As Long
Dim lLoadCase As Long
Dim dForceArray(6) As Double
Dim icount As Integer
Dim ret As Boolean
Dim path As String

path = Sheets("Main").Cells(185, 23).Value

Set staad = GetObject(, "StaadPro.OpenSTAAD")

staad.OpenSTAADFile path

'extract beam end forces

lMemberNo = Sheets("Main").Cells(184, 10).Value

For x = 2 To 6
lLoadCase = Sheets("SEISMIC").Range("B" & x).Value
ret = staad.Output.GetMemberEndForces(lMemberNo, lEnd, lLoadCase, dForceArray)

For icount = 0 To 5
Sheets("SEISMIC").Cells(x, 3 + icount).Value = dForceArray(icount)

Next icount
Next x

Set staad = Nothing

End Sub
```

However for the line:

```
Output.GetMemberEndForces(lMemberNo, lEnd, lLoadCase, dForceArray)
```

Only the **START** forces of the beam is extracted not the **END**.
[Excel and STAAD comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFrsT.jpg)

I wanted both. Is there a certain code that involves opening STAAD,
copying ALL member end forces? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

You can add a loop statement for "lend".

Example:

```
For lend = 0 to 1

For x = 2 To 6
lLoadCase = Sheets("SEISMIC").Range("B" & x).Value
ret = staad.Output.GetMemberEndForces(lMemberNo, lEnd, lLoadCase, dForceArray)

For icount = 0 To 5
Sheets("SEISMIC").Cells(x, 3 + icount).Value = dForceArray(icount)

Next icount
Next x

next lend
```

Although you still have to edit the code a bit to paste the results in different cells.